# local_costmap global frame

Tags: navigation, odometry, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i do not have a odom frame and wanna use a local costmap. my question is what should i use instead ?
my tf tree is /map-> Nav -> Base_footprint -> base_stabilized -> base_link
i do not have any idea in all tutorials and in the doku the /odom is used... what can i use instead ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39753/local_costmap-global-frame/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-25**:
What is Nav?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The costmap needs to be in a fixed frame, i.e. frames that do not move in the world. Normally, only map and odom are fixed frames and since you do not have odom, using map should be fine.

The reason why odom is used in map is that map can "jump" because of the particle filter based localization algorithm. If that happens, obstacles get sort of blurred because different cells are set in the costmap. Odometry is continuous, i.e. no jumps can happen and the costmap isn't blurred.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-25**:
ok thanks, now i understand that all a little bit more. I use hector quadrotor so i do not know what /nav is exactly but i was watching in rviz an /nav is fixed...i do not move with the rest...should i use /nav or /map ? i have read in other questens that /nav is the odom frame ...is this possible ?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-26**:
You should probably read this: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html